# grpc with Vertx Logs Explanation Needed

Tags: kotlin, grpc, vert.x, grpc-java

I have implemented a grpc API with Vertx using Kotlin and enabled FINEST log levels for debugging purposes. In my integration tests, I'm trying to connect a grpc client to the server using a channel.

Client snippet:

```
    val clientAsync1 = ctx.async()
            val channel1 = VertxChannelBuilder
                    .forAddress(vertx, "localhost", 10000)
                    .usePlaintext(true)
                    .build()
            val stub1 = ExampleGrpc.newVertxStub(channel1)

            val request = builderUtil.buildRequest()

            stub1.attemptFriendship(request) { stream ->
                    stream.handler { response ->

                    }
            }
```

I'm seeing the following in the logs in my grpc verticle:

```
    [main] 2018-05-24T12:42:27.69+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] Exiting idle mode
    [grpc-default-executor-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:27.71+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] resolved address: {1}, config={2}
    [main] 2018-05-24T12:42:27.713+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] {1} created for {2}
    [main] 2018-05-24T12:42:27.759+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel]  [{0}] Created {1} for {2}
    [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:28.081+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel]  [{0}] {1} for {2} is ready
    [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:35.956+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] Created with target {1}
    [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:35.961+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] Exiting idle mode
    [grpc-default-executor-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:35.962+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] resolved address: {1}, config={2}
    [grpc-default-executor-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:35.962+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] {1} created for {2}
    [grpc-default-executor-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:35.963+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel]  [{0}] Created {1} for {2}
    [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:35.974+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel]  [{0}] {1} for {2} is ready
    [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:46.808+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] shutdown() called
    [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2018-05-24T12:42:46.81+09:00 FINE [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl]  [{0}] Shutting down
```

Could someone explain what do `[{0}]{1}{2}` mean? Note that there are several channels created to complete the test and responses are streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{0}` format is that of [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) which is the default formatter used by `java.util.logging`. When calling a method like [`log(Level level, String msg, Object[] params)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-), the `params` are supposed to get combined with the `msg` to form the log string. This is beneficial as that processing is avoided if the log is not printed.

As seen in the `java.util.logging.Logger` documentation:

> Typically, formatters use java.text.MessageFormat style formatting to format parameters, so for example a format string "{0} {1}" would format two parameters as strings.

The `java.util.logging.Formatter` configured in your environment doesn't seem to be doing this though.